# How to prevent JSONKit from escaping backslash from ASP.NET JSON date format?

Tags: iphone, asp.net, objective-c, json, ios

I am using [JSONKit](https://github.com/johnezang/JSONKit) to encode/decode JSON between an ASP.NET RESTful service.

The date format used by the service is talked about [here](http://weblogs.asp.net/bleroy/archive/2008/01/18/dates-and-json.aspx) and looks like:

```
"\/Date(1198908717056)\/"
```

The problem is that when JSONKit processes a string that looks like above it escapes the backslash so the end result looks like this:

```
"\\/Date(1198908717056)\\/"
```

The JSON spec says you can optionally escape the forward slash (/) so JSONKit should interpret the **"\/"** as is and not escape the backslash.

Does anyone know of a way to prevent JSONKit from escaping the backslash when it is followed by a forward slash like the case above for ASP.NET JSON date formats?

Comment: I’ve just read your bug report. I agree with John’s arguments and I understand his reluctance in having yet another `if` in his highly performant parser when the JSON specification doesn’t require him to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Edit:** Forget the previous answer. As John mentioned, it’s probably incorrect and have side effects. John’s [committed a change](https://github.com/johnezang/JSONKit/issues/21#issuecomment-1090021) that implements an option called `JKSerializeOptionEscapeForwardSlashes` which should solve your problem.

---

<s>Even though the parser in JSONKit seems to handle `\/`, it looks like the generator doesn’t. In `jk_encode_add_atom_to_buffer()`:</s>

```
if(JK_EXPECT_F(utf8String[utf8Idx] >= 0x80U)) { encodeState->atIndex = startingAtIndex; goto slowUTF8Path; }
```

It’s a non-ASCII character, go to `slowUTF8Path`.

```
if(JK_EXPECT_F(utf8String[utf8Idx] <  0x20U))
```

It’s a control character (like `\n` or `\t`), escape it.

```
if(JK_EXPECT_F(utf8String[utf8Idx] == '\"') || JK_EXPECT_F(utf8String[utf8Idx] == '\\')) { encodeState->stringBuffer.bytes.ptr[encodeState->atIndex++] = '\\'; }
```

It’s a double quote or a backslash, escape it — and here lies the error since it doesn’t take into account `\/`.

I’ve patched JSONKit.m so that it does the following:

```
if(JK_EXPECT_F(utf8String[utf8Idx]) == '\\' && JK_EXPECT_F(utf8String[utf8Idx+1]) == '/') {
    encodeState->stringBuffer.bytes.ptr[encodeState->atIndex++] = '\\';
    encodeState->stringBuffer.bytes.ptr[encodeState->atIndex++] = '/';
    utf8Idx++;
}
else if(JK_EXPECT_F(utf8String[utf8Idx] == '\"') || JK_EXPECT_F(utf8String[utf8Idx] == '\\')) { encodeState->stringBuffer.bytes.ptr[encodeState->atIndex++] = '\\'; }
else encodeState->stringBuffer.bytes.ptr[encodeState->atIndex++] = utf8String[utf8Idx];
```

and my test program correctly generates the JSON fragment for your string:

```
NSString *test = @"\\/Date(1198908717056)\\/";
NSLog(@"%@", [test JSONString]);
```

outputs:

```
"\/Date(1198908717056)\/"
```

Without my patch, the program outputs:

```
"\\/Date(1198908717056)\\/"
```

That said, I recommend you [file a bug report with JSONKit](https://github.com/johnezang/JSONKit/issues). John is certainly the best person to fix this and JSONKit is far too optimised for me to have confidence in this patch; I’m not familiar with JSONKit at all. Feel free to refer him to this post.