# How to keep json-framwork from escaping the backslash when formatting date for WCF service in JSON

Tags: iphone, wcf, json, json-framework

I have noted the answer for JSONKit here: [How to prevent JSONKit from escaping backslash from ASP.NET JSON date format?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5844525/how-to-prevent-jsonkit-from-escaping-backslash-from-asp-net-json-date-format) but was wondering if there is a similar way using JSON-framework to keep it from escaping the backslash character in the WCF JSON date format: "\/Date(251683200000)\/"?

Comment: FYI, I ended up switching over to JSONKit after attempting to add the fix in to Json-framwork unsuccessfully.  I'll propose that answer in a couple days unless someone has an answer to my specific question or confirms its not possible.  BTW, JSONKit is really easy to get started out of the box, wish I had been using it sooner.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not possible in JSON-Framwork.  Switched to JSON kit which only took about 10 mins and seems like a much cleaner framwork as well.

Comment: Yes, this seems to confirm it: https://github.com/stig/json-framework/issues/1 :(

Comment: I thought I had this problem, but it turns out I had the name of the parameter wrong (duh), and in reality all works if I send `"/Date(123123123)/"`! I'm using WCF on the server side with `WebMessageFormat.Json`